# Command Pattern confusion

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Command Pattern Says:

Command Pattern allows you to decouple  the requester of an action from the object that actually performs the action.

Command decouples the object that invokes the operation from the one that knows how to perform it .

But in all code examples which I found there is coupling between Client(Requester,Inovker,RemoteControl,Waitress,Sender) and the actual object (Reciver,TV,Garage,Coffe)

If you this  question in the below 
[Command pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125298/command-pattern)

Answer:  Says : Your **remote doesn't know that the TV exists**, or anything about it, its just calling an interface/method on your Command object.

But I see Remote Class is aware of TV class and  it (remote) is creating object of TV class. Hence there is association there by a relation i.e  A coupling already exists there.

Can you please help me to understand what I am missing. Do I misunderstand what is meant by decoupling or some thing other ?

I am really confusing with definition.

Comment: Actually a remote does not know if there is a TV or not there. A remote will still send message regardless there is TV or not.

Comment: `Remote` does not actually (need to) know `TV`. The "example (in pseudo world)" just showed that somewhere an instance of `TV` was created and the `command` was initialized with that. Then the `remote` just got that `command` "somehow" (how exactly is just an implementation detail) an can now work with it.

Answer (score 1):

I think instead of TV it should be an interface like ITV

```
public class TVOffCommand : Command    
{
    ITV tv;

    public TVOffCommand (ITV aTV)
    {
        this.tv= aTv;
    }

    #region Command Members

    public object Execute()
    {
        return tv.Off();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

and your remote should invoke something like below:

**ITV** tv = new TV()

remote = new Remote()  //your client

command = new TVOffCommand(tv);

remote.command(command);

Have a look at link this provides the concept http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165368/WPF-MVVM-Quick-Start-Tutorial

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it make sense to wrap the example regarding TV and remote control into **command** design pattern. You just have TV and remote control. Even if you would add interfaces, it does not make sense as there is *small* (or no) level of abstraction.

The last sentence is the whole point of command design pattern. There must be some abstraction and unawarness. Typically you have some system which accept executable command (using defined `IF` = contract) which does "something".

It's up to your implementations of this `IF`, typically there is more implementations than one. What was my last use?

We have scheduling system using Quartz framework. We have wrapped it into some kind of our service. This service accepts our `IF` having `perform` method in a certain time - using quartz.

We have two types of executable tasks - one was executed immediately and second was was rescheduled with additional time - because of other reasons out of scope of this question.

Both types of tasks were executed **despite what they do**, despite they real executable code. **And** the wrapping service has **no knowledge** what's going on there and both types of tasks have **no knowledge regarding** scheduling system.